# 3-D Image construction from a 1D array

Tags: imagej

I have a plugin where I take an ImageJ image stack (3d) and convert it to a 1d array of floats to be sent for further processing by native code called using the JNA (Java  Native Interface). Now once I complete the processing and get back the modified 1D image array , I do not know how to convert it back to an Image stack. This question has been answered for just a 2-D image but I would like to convert it back to an image stack in the most efficient manner possible and then display the image. Also, the pixels are stored in the following manner in the 1D array. To access the pixel at location (x,y,z) in the image, you would go to element:

`[(z * width * height) + (height * y) + y]`  in the 1D array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a way to do this:

```
outputstack = ImageStack(x, y, z )  

for i in xrange(0, z):

    # Get the slice at index i and assign array elements corresponding to it.

    outputstack.setPixels(Array1D[int(i*x*y):int((i+1)*x*y)], i+1)

outputImp = ImagePlus("Output Image", outputstack)
```

Hope this helps other people.